# How to slice or acces a row of a Tensor?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, slice

I have a dataset stored in a 3D Tensor. I'd like to have an own tensor per each sample for profiling purposes. Unfortunately I only know the *brute force* method of accessing such a container:

```
auto tensor_dataset_map = dataset.tensor<float,3>();
for(int sample = 0; sample < maxSamples; sample++)
   for(int time = 0; time < periodSize; time++)
      for(int feature = 0; feature < amountOfFeatures; feature++)
         cout << tensor_dataset_map(sample,time,feature);
```

I would love to avoid this. However if I try with common sense to get all elements for the first sample (=0):

```
tensor_dataset_map(0)
```

it is the same like

```
tensor_dataset_map(0,0,0)
```

which is of shape `(1)` and I need tensors of shape `(1,periodSize,amountOfFeatures)`

Is there an easy way for this I do I really have to go this unoptimized way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer in the source code. Each Tensor has the function `Slice(): Slice this tensor along the 1st dimension.` where one needs to state the parameters begin of slicing and offset.

In other words for iterating in my case one needs to:

```
cout<<dataset.Slice(0,1).tensor<float,3>()<<endl
cout<<dataset.Slice(1,2).tensor<float,3>()<<endl
cout<<dataset.Slice(2,3).tensor<float,3>()<<endl
cout<<dataset.Slice(3,4).tensor<float,3>()<<endl
...
```

But because the lack of other documentation I think this might get deprecated